# How to reduce response time while using hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jersey

I am trying to fetch some data from database. And I am using Hibernate framework for fetching, It is taking more than 40 sec for create session and getting db values. I heard that normally it taking only millisec range. What is the actual problem. Please suggest possible mistake that I made.

```
public Map<String, String> regions() {

    Map<String, String> regionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Criteria criteria = getTemplate().getSession().createCriteria(LocationMaster.class);
    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("name"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("id"));
    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);

    ArrayList<Object[]> regionList = (ArrayList<Object[]>) getTemplate().get(criteria);

    System.out.println(regionList.get(0));
    for (Object[] list : regionList) {
        regionMap.put(list[0].toString(), list[1].toString());
        System.out.println(list[0]);
        System.out.println(list[1]);

    }
    Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>(regionMap);
    return map;

}
```

this is the code and I am not using DAO.

```
public Session getSession() {
    try {
        if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
            session = factory.openSession();
            txn = session.beginTransaction();
        }
    } catch (JDBCConnectionException e) {

        logger.error("JDBC Connection Exception   " + e.getStackTrace());
        System.out.println("JDBC Connection Exception   " + e.getStackTrace());

        factory.close();
        factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session = factory.openSession();
        txn = session.beginTransaction();

    }
    return session;
}

public HibernateTemplate() {
    if (factory == null || !factory.isClosed()) {
        System.out.println("hibernate constructor");
        factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    }

}
```

this is my getsession() method.

Comment: what amount of data you are trying to fetch??

Comment: are you using HQL queries or MySQL queries to fetch the data ? If you use MYSQL, it will take time to compile and get it executed.

Comment: I am using HQL. And data I am trying to fetch is 6 nos.